# How to determine the exact iOS version using Google Analytics

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, google-analytics

While reading [a tutorial on Google Analytics for iOS](http://www.raywenderlich.com/53459/google-analytics-ios) I wanted to know which version of iOS I was running.

I've googled for phrases like ["ios version google analytics"](http://www.google.com/#q=%22ios%2Bversion%2Bgoogle%2Banalytics%22) but couldn't find anything useful.

Basically I want to know the number of users running my app on any iOS version, e.g. iOS 6, iOS 7 etc.

I've also checked the Google Analytics documentation, but couldn't find a proper method. The device info on Google Analytics dashboard just shows "iPhone" but does not mention the iOS version.

Is there a way to get the exact iOS version via Google Analytics?

Comment: Its a valid question I don't see why he should get so many down votes.

Comment: @AlexanderKosubek I was doing this http://www.raywenderlich.com/53459/google-analytics-ios tutorial and wanted to know what version of iOS i was running...apparently I didn't look well enough in the documentation. I did a google search with a combination of phrases "ios version google analytics" etc..I found results for Safari version...I also checked accross GA Dashboard. I suppose I should've looked deeper into "Views" before questioning

Comment: may b he is not exactly asking what he has in mind..

Comment: @QualityCoder I'v written that I want to know the number of users running my app on iOS 6, and number of users running iOS 7.

Comment: @TusharKoul I took the liberty to put most of your additional info into the question. As the underlying question is valid, the downvotes may thus "go away" easier.

Comment: i was about to add that in the question..thanks anyways @AlexanderKosubek

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I created you a custom report so you can see how the information is saved.  [Os Custom Report](https://www.google.com/analytics/web/template?uid=Yf9PGf0EQFGwpKMMV9h4cA)

I think what you are after is [Operating system](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets#view=detail&group=platform_or_device&jump=ga_operatingsystem) and [Operating system version.](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets#view=detail&group=platform_or_device&jump=ga_operatingsystemversion)

Comment: Thanks for the answer..I think I need to spend some more time on the Dashboard in order to get more used to the "Views"...

Comment: It takes time. I have been working with it for a year and a half now and I still find things I hadn't seen before.

Answer (score 1):

There is a method, go to

Audience > Technology > Browser & OS > The browser version matches the firmware*.

Might not match exactly, but in my experience its more than accurate enough and I am 95% it does match always.

Hope that helps Tushar

Answer (score 1):

So I was looking for a solution here as well. I came across this article by Phillip Studiniski that shows you how to measure the iPhone screens by screen resolution.

https://analytical42.com/2017/detect-and-track-iphone-models-in-google-analytics/

I attempted to go this route. The problem I ran into was that I was just getting a raw output of the screen resolution in GTM, it would look something like this.

{"width":375,"height":667,"ratio":2.0000000454608653}

No problem I thought. I moved this into a RegEx table. [Click here to see a sample RegEx for this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HNf51.png) Once I did this, I was able to properly identify the iPhone version with a variable and then send it to Google Analytics through Google Tag Manager variable.

I then had to update the iPhone models a bit since it has been a while since the article was written. (https://iosref.com/res) This includes the models from 11 to 13.

BOOM! iPhone version now being sent to GA. Hope this helps everyone.